# The code after isset($_GET['edit']) not working

Tags: php

I can't make the code That is used to update to work it's like the $_GET method not working

Everything in working fine I can Delete and Insert in database But I can't Update, when the submit button value is changed to edit and I click it, it does not execute the Update statment instead it executes the Insert statment

```
           <?php 


     $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand ORDER BY brand";
     $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     $datarows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     if(isset($_GET['delete']) && !empty($_GET['delete'])) {

        $deleteid = (int)$_GET['delete'];

        $sql = "DELETE FROM brand WHERE Bra_ID = ?";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($deleteid));
        header("Location: brands.php");
        exit();
     }

     if (isset($_GET['edit']) && !empty($_GET['edit'])) {

        $editid = (int)$_GET['edit'];

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE Bra_ID = ?";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($editid));
        $brandsrows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } 

     if (isset($_POST['submit']) ) {

        $brand = sanitize($_POST['brand']);
        $errors = array();

        if (empty($brand)) {
             $errors[] = "Please Enter Brand Name";

        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE brand = '$brand'";

        if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {  //This not working work
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE brand = '$brand' AND 
                         Bra_ID != '$editid'";
        }

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($count > 0) {  
               $errors[] = $brand . " Brand Already Exists";    
        } 

        if (!empty($errors)) {
             echo displayErrors($errors);

        } else {

            if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { //This not working work
            $sql = "UPDATE brand SET brand = '''$brand' WHERE 
                    Bra_ID='$editid'";
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO brand(brand) VALUES('$brand')";

            $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            header("Location: brands.php");
            exit();
        }

     } 
        ?>
          <div class="container-fluid" style="height: 750px">
              <h1 class="text-center my-3">Brands Area</h1>
           <hr> 

           <div class="brand-add">
             <form action="brands.php" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                <label for=""><?=(isset($_GET['edit'])?'Brand To Edit: 
                  ':'Brand Name: ')?></label>
        <?php
            $brandName ='';
            if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                $brandName = $brandsrows[0]['brand'];
            } else {
                if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                    $brandName = $_POST['brand'];
                }
            }
        ?>
             <input type="text" class="form-control mx-2" name="brand" 
                 value="<?=$brandName?>">
          <?php 
        if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
                ?>
         <a href="brands.php" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-1">Cancel</a>
                <?php
        }
        ?>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
             value="<?=(isset($_GET['edit'])?'Edit':'Add')?> New Brand">
          </form>
        </div>   
          <hr>
        <table class="table table-bordered width-auto table-condensed">
            <thead>
             <tr>
               <th scope="col"></th>
               <th scope="col">Brands</th>
               <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

      <?php 

        foreach ($datarows as $rows) {

       ?>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a href="brands.php?edit=<?php echo $rows['Bra_ID'] ?>" 
                class="btn btn-success"> <i class="far fa-edit"></i>
             </a>
           </td>
         <td class="text-primary font-weight-bold"><?php echo $rows['brand'] ?> 
       </td>
         </td>
         <td>
        <a href="brands.php?delete=<?php echo $rows['Bra_ID'] ?>" class="btn 
            btn-danger confirm">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
        </a>
       </td>
       </tr>

       <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


I want the statment That's used to Update to Work, it's like it dosen't existe Please Help
```

Comment: This code is very confusing.  What does your HTML become in the browser, after its been rendered by the PHP code?  What specifically are you clicking on in that HTML?  Also, consistent and sensible indentation and other whitespace in your PHP code will make it *much* easier to read and follow.  Not just for us, but for you.

Comment: At the very least you have a syntax error on this line `<td class="text-primary font-weight-bold"><?php echo $rows['brand']>`. It should be `<td class="text-primary font-weight-bold"><?php echo $rows['brand']; ?>`

Comment: You also have a line that is invalid and would cause PHP errors. `displays errors` looks like it is meant to be part of the line before it as a comment but, as posted, it isn't and would raise an error.

Comment: The code looks clean in my code editor it's just when I pasted it here it looks like that, and the syntax error it's not an error in my code it happend when I paste it here too. please do your best to fugure out why update statment does not work when $_GET method isset. Thank you

Comment: @nesmaaboki: *"please do your best to fugure out why"* - You seem to be misunderstanding what this community does.  If the code you're showing us is different from the code you're using, regardless of what copy/paste issues may exist, *you* need to correct it to the actual code being used.  Additionally, requests for clarification have been made and you have yet to respond to them.  It is *highly unlikely* that anybody here will be able (or even willing) to correct anything for you if you are unwilling to put in any effort at all.

Comment: It's not that I'm not willing to put an effort. it's my first time to put that much code here, sorry if I sounded lazy but I didn't mean it at all. I correct the code to look more readable. please help, thank you.

Comment: It's because that code is inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also thought about that so how I can fix the code to work

Comment: The Solution is to make an if statment inside form action if $_GET isset. Thank you all for sharing your thoughts

Answer (score -1):

Databases are *transactional* this means that after every statement (like an email) you must send it **and then** wait for a reply (if you are expecting one).

```
        if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { //This not working work
          $sql = "UPDATE brand SET brand = '$brand' WHERE 
                  Bra_ID='$editid'";

          //UPDATE query transaction
          $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
          $stmt->execute();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO brand(brand) VALUES('$brand')";

        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Because you did not execute the command, the variable $sql was being overwritten

```
         if (isset($_GET['edit'])) { //This not working work
         $sql = "UPDATE brand SET brand = '''$brand' WHERE 
                 Bra_ID='$editid'";
         }
         $sql = "INSERT INTO brand(brand) VALUES('$brand')";
         echo($sql);
         $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->execute();
```

In the above statement $sql would echo the INSERT command because it overwrote the previous statement *and then* was executed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but it still ignoring the Update statment and executing only the Insert statment

Comment: The SQL user probably does not have EDIT/UPDATE permission

Comment: Thank you, What do you mean by SQL user

Comment: SQL permissions are rarely the problem. 95% of the time the root user is being used.

Comment: I know now what you mean by sql permission, I checked it and it's not the problem, it's like it ignores the Update statment when it's inside the if (isset($_GET['edit']). when I tested it without the if and removed the Insert  statment it works. it seems the problem is wih isset($_GET['edit'] but I don't know what it is

Comment: I found the problome. it seems that $_GET[edit] is returning empty value when it's inside if $_POST[submit]. How can I fix that. Thank you

Comment: I found out what's the problem. I removed the action from the form